# WeasyPrint server error 500 on render.com

Tags: django, server, weasyprint, render.com

im having a 'server error 500' in my project when i tried to use Weasyprint (im not having any error when i use local host), I deploy my project on render.com it's a django app with postrgres.

here is the code:

```
    html_template = get_template('printinfo.html')
    html_string = html_template.render({'person': passanger})
    html_string = html_template.render(context)
    pdf_file = HTML(string=html_string).write_pdf()
    response = HttpResponse(pdf_file, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'filename="{passanger.passanger.name} Reservation.pdf"'
    return response
```

Im thinking its an enviroment error but i installed my requirements.txt in render.com which has weasyprint on it.

I tried to find a way to install gtk or pango in render.com but i couldnt find the way...